# Загрузка картинки и отправка в чат Telegram

Tags: java, telegram, telegrambots

Класс Bot:

```
    public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
        private long chatId;
        Document document;
        Parser parser = new Parser();

    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        update.getUpdateId();

        chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();
        Message msg = update.getMessage();

        if (msg != null && msg.hasText()) {
            //if(msg.getText().equals("/start")) {

            SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage().setChatId(chatId);
            try {
                sendMessage.setText(parser.ParseText(msg.getText()));
                execute(sendMessage);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            SendPhoto sendPhoto = new SendPhoto().setChatId(chatId);
            try {
                sendPhoto.setPhoto(parser.ParseImg(msg.getText()));
                execute(sendPhoto);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "@ParseSteamBot";
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return "...";
    }
}
```

Класс Parser:

```
public File ParseImg(String href) {
    File file;

    try {
        document = Jsoup.connect(href).get();
        Elements img = document.getElementsByClass("game_header_image_full");

        try(InputStream in = new URL(img.attr("src")).openStream()){
            Files.copy(in, Paths.get("C\\images\\"));
            return new File("C\\images\\");
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Image not found...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Ошибки возникают в строках с блоком try...catch

```
.java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C\images
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:230)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:434)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:216)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:3016)
    at Parser.ParseImg(Parser.java:60)
    at Bot.onUpdateReceived(Bot.java:36)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:306)

мая 06, 2019 6:55:59 PM org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.logging.BotLogger severe
SEVERE: BOTSESSION
java.lang.NullPointerException: file cannot be null!
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendPhoto.setPhoto(SendPhoto.java:111)
    at Bot.onUpdateReceived(Bot.java:36)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:306)
```

Хотя при первом же запуске код сработал и загрузил одну картинку. Думаю, это блокировки со стороны сервера из-за частых запросов

Comment: У вас не находится файл из-за того что он(или так считает JVM) нулевой. Вы уверены, что никак не изменяете файл/путь и т.п. при первом запуске?

Comment: @AntonSorokin, менял путь несколько раз в этих строчках try(InputStream in = new URL(img.attr("src")).openStream()){
            Files.copy(in, Paths.get("C\\images\\"));
            return new File("C\\images\\");
        }

Comment: Может дело в двоеточии: "C:\\images\\my_picture.png". 

А вообще в Java вне зависимости от ОС можно так:
"C:/images/my_picture.png". Используйте библиотеку Commons IO, а не эту фигню с JDK.

Comment: @SadrutdinZaynukov,  "C:/images/my_picture.png" - этот способ помог. Спасибо!

Comment: Не очень понимаю, как создать класс Parser
Его надо создавать в отдельном классе?
И как сделать тип возвращаемого значения(Если я не ошибаюсь, что это оно) "File"?
Сейчас тоже пытаюсь добавить в телеграм бота отправку фото по запросу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может дело в двоеточии: "C:\images\my_picture.png". А вообще в Java вне зависимости от ОС можно так: "C:/images/my_picture.png". Используйте библиотеку Commons IO, а не эту фигню с JDK. – Sadrutdin Zaynukov